# C++ template class prototype, function definiton

Tags: c++, class, templates

I want to write a function that creates a "Vector" (template), stores a couple of values in it, then returns that vector.  I'm defining the function below "main" and so am using the prototype:

```
Vector<double> VectorMouseClick;
```

Is this the correct prototype?

After "main" I'm defining the function and am trying to do it this way but am not sure if it's the correct way to do it:

```
Vector<double> VectorMouseClick()
{
    Vector<double> vector();
     ...some code manipulating values and storing them in "vector"...
    return vector;
}
```

If a function is returning a class I specify (aka Vector), how do I write the prototype?  Since it's a template class do I do it like above:
    Vector VectorMouseClick;
or is it:
    Vector VectorMouseClick; 
(as like the other prototypes (int ReturnValues, void SomeFunct, etc)

When exactly can I use "void" on a prototype?  Is this only for functions that don't "return" a value?  I've looked through the answers on here but as I'm new to C++ some of them are a little hard to understand.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you're new to C++, then a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) will make your life much easier. There are a lot of quirks that will be very difficult to figure out for yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this the correct prototype?

No, you need parentheses to indicate that it's a function (empty, since the function takes no arguments):

```
Vector<double> VectorMouseClick();
```

Without the parentheses, you are declaring a variable, not a function.

> If a function is returning a class I specify (aka Vector), how do I write the prototype?

In general a function declaration is always `return_type function_name(arguments);` (perhaps with a few extra bits and pieces). A class is a type, so just give its name as the return type. A class *template* isn't a class (or a type), so you need to provide the template arguments to make it a class.

> When exactly can I use "void" on a prototype? Is this only for functions that don't "return" a value?

That's exactly right. `void` is used in places where you have to give a type, but there isn't any type to give; in the case of a function return type, it indicates that nothing is returned.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not. In general:

```
T t;
```

declares a variable of type T named t.

```
T t();
T t(void);
```

is both the same way to declare a function taking no parameter, returning T and being named t.

Using one or the other is merely a style issue, since in C the void was necessary, while in C++ it is not. When you don't return any value, then the return type of the function is `void`.